# Autofill on another sheet not working after autofilling the active sheet (no error)

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I'm trying to rewrite my code to avoid select and avtivate but I'm running into a problem. It's probably something simple but I'd appreciate the help.

I've been looking for a similar issue but haven't found one so sorry if this is a duplicate.

When I'm running my code, the select case works, the autofill on `("Artikelen maken")` works but the other sheet won't autofill

```
Public rngab As Range
Public rngc As Range
Public rngdk As Range
Public rngac As Range
Public rngdi As Range
Public rngrow As Range

Sub samenstelling1()

Set rngrow = ActiveSheet.Rows(2)
Set rngab = ActiveSheet.Range("a2:b2")
Set rngc = ActiveSheet.Range("c2")
Set rngdk = ActiveSheet.Range("d2:k2")
Set rngac = ActiveSheet.Range("a2:c2")
Set rngdi = ActiveSheet.Range("d2:i2")

        Case Is = 2
            With Sheets("Artikelen_aanmaken")
                rngrow.Offset(19).Resize(10).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                rngab.AutoFill Destination:=rngab.Resize(2), Type:=xlFillSeries
                rngc.AutoFill Destination:=rngc.Resize(2), Type:=xlFillDefault
                rngdk.AutoFill Destination:=rngdk.Resize(2), Type:=xlFillSeries
            End With

                With Sheets("Artikelen_in_stuklijsten")      'also tried with .activate
                    rngrow.Offset(19).Resize(10).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    rngac.AutoFill Destination:=rngac.Resize(2), Type:=xlFillSeries

                    rngdi.AutoFill Destination:=rngdi.Resize(2), Type:=xlFillDefault
                    'does work as
                    'rngac.Select
                    'Selection.AutoFill Destination:=rngac.Resize(2), Type:=xlFillSeries
                End With
```

---

This is the working code I'm trying to rewrite btw

```
'             Sheets("Artikelen_in_stuklijsten").Activate
'             Range("18:30").EntireRow.Hidden = True
'             Range("A2:c2").Select
'             Range("A2:c2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:c3"), Type:=xlFillSeries
'             Range("d2:i2").Select
'             Range("d2:i2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("d2:i3"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

---

Fixed it with this:

```
Set rngrow = Sheets("Artikelen_aanmaken").Rows(2)
Set rngab = Sheets("Artikelen_aanmaken").Range("a2:b2")
Set rngc = Sheets("Artikelen_aanmaken").Range("c2")
Set rngdk = Sheets("Artikelen_aanmaken").Range("d2:k2")
Set rngac = Sheets("Artikelen_in_stuklijsten").Range("a2:c2")
Set rngdi = Sheets("Artikelen_in_stuklijsten").Range("d2:i2")

Samenstelling.UserForm_Initialize
Samenstelling.Show

Range("q500") = letter
Range("N500") = tekeningnr
Range("P500") = revletter
Range("R500") = omschrijving
Range("O500") = posnummer

Select Case posnummer
Case Is = 4
                With Sheets("Artikelen_aanmaken").Activate
                    rngrow.Offset(19).Resize(10).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    rngab.AutoFill Destination:=rngab.Resize(4), Type:=xlFillSeries
                    rngc.AutoFill Destination:=rngc.Resize(4), Type:=xlFillDefault
                    rngdk.AutoFill Destination:=rngdk.Resize(4), Type:=xlFillSeries
                End With

                    Sheets("Artikelen_in_stuklijsten").Activate
                        rngrow.Offset(19).Resize(10).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        rngac.Select
                        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=rngac.Resize(4), Type:=xlFillSeries
                        rngdi.Select
                        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=rngdi.Resize(4), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: There are some peculiarities in your code that I'm not sure if you made by mistake or not. `Case Is = 2` and the lack of dots in your `With`s are the top two things I'm thinking of.

Comment: @Sam Definitely by mistake, I'm a beginner. `case is = 2` is just part of my select case but I didn't want to paste the entire code. What dots am I missing in my `with` statement so I can improve that. Thank you

Comment: `With something` is shorthand for saying everything inside the `With` starting with `.` will be interpreted as `something.ThatComesAfterTheDot`. In your case, I think you should move the `Set rng...` into the withs. Delete `ActiveSheet`, but keep the dot.

Comment: @Sam I'm trying to avoid having the `set rng` in the `with` because the `select case` is 16 long with all of the cases having 2 `with` statements in them. If nothing works I'll just revert back to `rng.select` and then `selection.autofill...`

Comment: Adding dots in front of the `with` statements gives an error sadly

Answer (score 0):

I have rearranged your code a bit, but I haven't tested it. See it more as an explanation of a concept, than a working solution:

```
With Sheets("Artikelen_aanmaken")
    Set rngrow = .Rows(2)
    Set rngab = .Range("a2:b2")
    Set rngc = .Range("c2")
    Set rngdk = .Range("d2:k2")
    Set rngac = .Range("a2:c2")
    Set rngdi = .Range("d2:i2")

    rngrow.Offset(19).Resize(10).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    rngab.AutoFill Destination:=rngab.Resize(2), Type:=xlFillSeries
    rngc.AutoFill Destination:=rngc.Resize(2), Type:=xlFillDefault
    rngdk.AutoFill Destination:=rngdk.Resize(2), Type:=xlFillSeries
End With
```

Comment: You cannot set `.range` or `.row` (or maybe you can but only withing the `with` statement) so sadly that wouldn't work. I think I'm just going for select and activate because your concept would mean 32x the work that select would require. Thank you for trying to help though :)

Comment: sadly... the `rngac.select` only works up till case 3, from case 4 it give an error `method select of class range failed`. which is weird because I'm just selecting some cells.. But then I changed activate to select in the `with sheets(..)` line and then it worked for cae 1-4. and now it's broken again